# Slot Machine Game for Python 3

Tags: python

Write a program that acts as a simple “slot machine” .  The user starts with 100 tokens and with each “pull” of the handle loses 1 token.  The computer “spins” three wheels each consisting of the numbers 1, 2, and 3.  If all three numbers are 1, the user gets 4 tokens; if all three are 2, the user gets 8 tokens; if all are 3, the user gets 12 tokens.  The program output should look similar to:
You have 100 tokens.  Pull?  Y
[1]  [3]  [2]
You lost.
You have 99 tokens.  Pull? Y
[2]  [2]  [2]
You won 8 tokens!
You have 106 tokens.  Pull?  N
Thanks for playing!

```
import random


def slot_machine((a, b, c))
    tokens = 100
    points = 0
    while tokens > 0:
        a = random.randint(1, 3)
        b = random.randint(1, 3)
        c = random.randint(1, 3)
        if a and b and c == 1:
            point = points + 4
        elif a and b and c == 2:
            point = points + 8
        elif a and b and c == 3:
            point = points + 12
        else:
            print("you lost")
```

i have this so far, not too sure what to do for the input tho

Comment: Read the documentation for the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain on what the question is but ill do my best to help.

is this the code you want?

```
import random
import copy

def spin(points):
    a = random.randint(1, 3)
    b = random.randint(1, 3)
    c = random.randint(1, 3)
    print('[%s] [%s] [%s]' % (a, b, c))
    p = copy.copy(points);
    if a==1 and b==1 and c==1:
        p+=4
    if a==2 and b==2 and c==2:
        p+=8
    if a==3 and b==3 and c==3:
        p+=12
    return p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tokens = 100
    points = 0

    while input('continue? (Y/N): ') == 'Y':
        tokens -= 1
        points = spin(points)
        print('you now have %s points and %s tokens' % (points, tokens))
```